# Find minimum $f(x) = \sin (x) + \cos (x) + \sin (2 x) + 1$ for $x \in [0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

> Find minimum for $$f(x) = \sin (x) + \cos (x) + \sin (2 x) + 1$$ for $x \in
>  [0,2\pi]$

I tried compute derivative:

$$ \cos(x) + 2 \cos(2 x) - \sin(x) = 0 $$
Where solutions: 
$$x_n=-\frac{3\pi}{4} + n \pi$$

And it is that:
$$f(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 2 + \sqrt2 \text{ it is max}$$
$$f(\frac{5\pi}{4}) = 2 - \sqrt2 > 0$$

But how find minimum for $f(x)$?

I tried simulated this function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin%28x%29+%2B+cos%28x%29+%2B+sin%282x%29+%2B1%29%27+%3D%3D0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that $f(t)=t+t^2$ for $t=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$. Now recall that $t=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\in[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ for $x\in[0,2\pi]$. Therefore we reduced the problem to mininization of $f(t)=t+t^2$ on the interval $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$. The rest is clear.

Comment: Good answer, many thanks!